# Pencil mic windjammer recommendations

Tags: microphone, suspension-mounts, wind-protection, windshield, windjammer

I recently bought a pair of Line Audio's CM3 for stereo ambiance recording. I'm now looking for windjammers.

Anyone tested the [Rode WS8](http://www.rodemic.com/accessories/ws8)? they're pretty cheap.
My other options are : Rycote Baby ball, Schoeps W20 or Cinela Leo.

My goal is to be able to record large AB ambiences (each mic on his stand). 
Do you know if mic suspensions will be useful in my case or classic mic holder can work well ?
I'm also thinking of buying a Rode Blimp, I heard it can fit an ortf system with small mics like the CM3s.

Thank's in advance for any recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're recording outside, do yourself a favor and go with a Rycote Baby Ball Gag (well, a pair, obviously). They CM3's *might* fit in a single stereo windscreen (they're about 6mm longer than an MKH 80X0). (Be aware that Rycote makes windscreens in different sizes, some of which are much wider than the Rode Blimp, which might make fitment easier.)

I've done many, many recordings with just a foam windscreen and a fuzzy/dead cat/wombat and it just doesn't work reliably for the range of conditions you'll find outdoors. They're awesome for interiors to prevent wind noise from breaths, boompole swings, and outdoors on really calm days in sheltered locations, but they're nowhere near as flexible as a proper windscreen that holds a volume of still air around the mic. You don't want your gear dictating where and when you can record, especially for field recording, if you can help it.

Comment: Thank's for the advice. Is the baby ball (with furry) still effective under high wind ?
I've seen there http://thesoundmyheadmakes.blogspot.fr/2011/10/semi-stealth-recording-with-my-new-cm3s.html that they fit well in a Blimp, I have a tight budget.

Comment: I've had them strapped to bicycles going 15mph and similar-force natural wind and they've been great!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post [Small XLR connecotrs for ORTF setup](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/20561/small-xlr-connecotrs-for-ortf-setup/20570?noredirect=1#comment18708_20570) here you´ll find some pics and recommendations for building cm3´s inside the Rode Blimp which works pretty well !!