# Small XLR connecotrs for ORTF setup

Tags: ambience, sound-effects-recording

Im planning to setup an ORTF setup in my RODE Blimp with a pair of Line Audio CM3 & Im looking for small XLR connectors so i can setup ORTF easily.

Please check out this image 
[image]

I saw this image in gearslutz & im wondering if i can get the xlr connector in this image?

has anybody used these kind of xlr connectors? were can i get this kinda this?

Looking froward to hearing from you guys.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

I use exactly what your planing. I use two line audio cm3 with the kortwich connectors. In a ORTF Setup Which is a little Wider (21cm) than normal but it sounds very nicely. You can order the connectors at http://www.filmtontechnik.de/service.html or you can write them a email via mail@filmtontechnik.de There are very nice people in the Store in Berlin. I´m not one of them, but i order stuff there. They build the cables on Order. Which means, that you can choose cable lenghts, etc.... very good quiality..
And **i paid 39 €** for them here in Germany. The Link from Rene is really quite expensive...

The Setup fits very nice, very versatile, suspension works great even while carrying around. [image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: WOW that's superb andreas. This is the exact setup im planning for.BTW from where id you get the mic holder?

Comment: @BalaHariharan This are the original micholders from line audio. They arrived with the mics. BTW: If you find an other /better/different mounting option, let me know. At the moment it works very well but maybe there is a better option which i don´t see.

Comment: Sure Andreas, Im still waiting for my CM3's - as soon as i get it all set i'll post you my setup with pics :)

Comment: Hi Andreas. how do you get the mic's stable in this setup? i've been remodelling it from you pictures but it's a bit wonky. oh btw instead of using tape to stick them together, i use a sawed off screw that fits the clamps internal thread. works perfect!

Comment: Oh, I used a screw also... it was just, that i can´t tighten it as hard as i wanted because of the angle with was not correct in the end....

Answer (score 1):

If you're into it, you can DIY it.  Get some Neutrik connectors (or cables with the connectors- easier IMO), remove the plastic bits, and put a notch in the remaining metal housing.  Get the cable snug in the notch, and epoxy it together.  Not the most elegant solution, but very inexpensive.

Check here:
http://taperssection.com/index.php?topic=131555.0

DPA makes a similar cable, but the price is even higher than the Kortwich:
http://www.dpamicrophones.com/en/products.aspx?c=Item&category=144&item=24412

Answer (score 0):

Kortwich ftw.  pricey, but the only once on the market that I know with that low profile of a construction.

http://www.pro-sound.com/Merchant2/merchant.mvc?Screen=PROD&Store_Code=PSS&Product_Code=SKOR0006A&Category_Code=Kortwich

Answer (score 0):

I tried the exact same thing (same mics and blimp). It worked out fine but be prepared to "lose" your blimp in the process. After all was said and done the setup was married to the blimp. Later when I needed to use it for my 416 I never reasembled the ORTF rig. It was just too much of a pain going back and forth.

Although if you don't need the blimp for anything else, then no worries.

For the connectors, what I did was remove everything from a neutrik connector that wasn't needed. So you're left with the cable soldered to the little plastic piece, which leaves the tiniest of footprint. Then I used heat shrink tubing over the whole thing. This added strength and piece of mind to the assembly.

The above setup worked well. For other setups I might not go with the heat shrink tubing, but since this is in the blimp, and the cables are gripped pretty tightly when you screw on the end caps, I never had problems with them coming detached.

Hope that's of help to you. Good luck with it!

Comment: Thanks man, Yes ive planned to use this blimp only for ORTF & for shot gun i have a rycote softie +i'll try the heat shrink tubing aswell. Cheers!!!